# release object added to Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am importing a good amount of data into my application using Core Data like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) 
{
    Client *entity = (Client*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [entity setCompanyName:[[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"CompanyName"]];
    //* bunch of other fields

    NSError *error;

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }   
}
```

What do I need to be releasing here?  should I be doing [entity release]?

Comment: You might benefit from moving the context save to outside the iteration loop, or leave it inside the loop, but only save after `n` iterations. (selecting a good value for `n` would be platform dependent, Mac OS X vs. iOS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> **insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:**
>   Despite the presence of the word “new” in the method name, in a reference counted environment you are not responsible for releasing the returned object.

So the answer is no, you don't need to release the `entity` variable.

Note this is the standard. When using a convenience method, returned instances are auto-released by convention, so you don't need to care about them, unless you explicitly retain them, of course.